# A Question on OpenGL ES 2.0 and Alpha / Stencil Tests

Tags: graphics, opengl-es

I have a quad covering the area between -0.5, 0.5 and 0.5, -0.5 on a cleared viewport with a stencil and alpha buffer.  In the fragment shader I apply a texture which happens to have a shape -- in this case a circle -- outside of which it is fully transparent.

I am trying to figure out how I can essentially "cut" that non-alpha textured shape out of the next draw of the shape, such that I draw the first quad, offset to some degree (say between -0.3, 0.5 and 0.8, -0.5) and draw again, and only the non-overlap of the non-alpha texture is drawn of the second quad's texture.

It is easy enough doing this with a stencil buffer, such that it applies to the quad and is blind to the texture, however I would like to apply it to the texture.

So as an example of the function what I want actually rendered of the conceptual circle texture would be a crescent in that case. I am not sure what tests I should be using for this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to stick with the stencil buffer, but the alpha test isn't available in ES 2.0 per the philosophy that anything that can be done in a shader isn't supplied as fixed functionality.

Instead, you can insert one of your own choosing inside the fragment shader, thanks to the `discard` keyword. Supposing you had the most trivial textured fragment shader:

```
varying mediump vec2 texCoordVarying;
uniform sampler2D tex2D;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying);
}
```

You could throw in an alpha test so that pixels with an alpha of less than 0.1 don't proceed down the pipeline, and hence don't affect the stencil buffer with:

```
varying mediump vec2 texCoordVarying;
uniform sampler2D tex2D;

void main()
{
    vec4 colour = texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying);

    if(colour.a > 0.1)
        gl_FragColor = colour;
    else
        discard;
}
```

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but I just wanted to add that this is terrible form on many GPUs as this will run far slower than just setting the color to 0. For instance, discarding and to some extent branching is regarded as a bad idea on iOS ES 2.0 SL

Comment: You're absolute right; if your blend mode permits it and you can live with the depth buffer write then it's faster to output a pixel with an alpha of 0 than to `discard`. It'd also be much faster to achieve that with, say, a subtraction, a clamp and an addition than with an explicit conditional. In both cases the GPU otherwise has to deal with conditionality, which means lower parallelism.